# Eigenvalues of the hyperbolic Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working on the following Linear Algebra problem:

Let $k$ be a field, let $d$ be a positive integer, and let $P_d$ be the $k$-vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq d$ in $k[x,y]$. The *hyperbolic Laplacian on polynomials of degree $d$* is the differential operator $D_d = -y^2(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})$. For each $d \leq 5$, compute the eigenvalues of $D_d$, and, for each eigenvalue, compute the dimension of the eigenspace. (Your answer will depend on $d$.)

Here is my work so far:

Let $f(x,y) = \sum_{i = 0}^d \sum_{j = 0}^d a_{i,j}x^iy^j \in k[x,y]$ be a $d$-dimensional polynomial, where $a_{i,j} \in k$. Then $D_d(f) = \lambda f$

$\Rightarrow -y^2(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}) = \lambda f$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{i = 0}^d \sum_{j = 0}^d i(1-i)a_{i,j}x^{i-2}y^{j+2} + \sum_{i = 0}^d \sum_{j = 0}^d j(1-j)a_{i,j}x^iy^j = \sum_{i = 0}^d \sum_{j = 0}^d a_{i,j} \lambda x^iy^j$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{i = 0}^d \sum_{j = 0}^d a_{i,j}[i(1-i)x^{i-2}y^{j+2} + (j(1-j)-\lambda)x^iy^j] = 0$

From the above equation, I'm struggling with finding the solutions for the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and their corresponding eigenspace dimensions. How do I deconstruct the above equation for my solutions for $\lambda$ ? It seems a bit overwhelming.

Thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting problem. There is a brute-force solution; just write the matrix of $D_5$ using a computer algebra system, and then ask it to compute the eigenvalues. Not a great advice, but that's the best I can come up with right now.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Hmm, I see ! That would be a great check. Unfortunately, this is a problem that appeared on an old preliminary exam (written) from my university's math department, so I'd be expected to do it brute force. It seems like I've reduced it down to an algebraic problem -- but it's still tough nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: For $d=0, 1$ the only eigenvalue is $0$, and for $d=2$ the eigenvalues are $0$ and $-2$, the only $-2$ eigenvector being $y^2$. I think that the remaining dimensions must just be done by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q_d$ denote the space of polynomials of total degree exactly $d$ in
$k[x,y]$. Then we have the direct sum decomposition
$P_d=\bigoplus_{k=0}^d Q_k$ and further each $Q_d$ is stable by $D$.

So, it suffices to study the eigenproperties of $D$ on each $Q_d$.
Next, if we put $b_j=y^jx^{d-j}$, notice that ${\cal B}=(b_{d},b_{d-1},b_{d-2},\ldots,b_{0})$ is a basis of $Q_d$ (in particular, $Q_d$ has dimension $d+1$).

Also, we have $D(b_{d})=-d(d-1)b_{d}, D(b_{d-1})=-(d-1)(d-2)b_{d-1}$ and $D(b_j)=-j(j-1)b_j-(d-j)(d-j-1)b_{d-j}$ for $j\lt d-1$. So the matrix of $D$ with respect to ${\cal B}$ is upper triangular, and this immediately gives us all the eigenvalues : they are the $f(j)=-j(j-1)$ for $0\leq j\leq d$ (note that some of those values may not be distinct).

The first values of $f$ are $f(0)=f(1)=0$, $f(2)=-2$, $f(3)=-6$, $f(4)=-12$ and
$f(5)=-20$.

So on $Q_d$, the eigenvalues of $D$ are $0$ with multiplicity $2$ (except for $d=0$ where it is $1$), and all the $f(k)$ for $k\leq d$, with multiplicity $1$.

Adding up, on $P_d$ the eigenvalues of $D$ are $0$ with multiplicity $2d+1$ (except for $d=0$ where it is $1$), and all the $f(k)$ for $k\leq d$, where $f(k)$ has multiplicity $d-k+1$.